# three.js three-nodes showing 'Module not found' error

Tags: reactjs, three.js, webgpu

`./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/renderers/webgpu/nodes/WebGPUNodeBuilder.js`
Module not found: Can't resolve 'three-nodes/core/CodeNode.js'.
I am using react, `import three from node_modules`, It throws an error like this.

What can I do to solve it?

Why "three-nodes/": "./jsm/nodes/" ?

Comment: ./node_modules/three/examples/jsm/renderers/webgpu/nodes/WebGPUNodeBuilder.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'three-nodes/core/CodeNode.js' in 'D:\1-projects\webgpuMapMaking\node_modules\three\examples\jsm\renderers\webgpu\nodes'

Answer (score 1):

I think this GitHub Issue is relevant:
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/24377

`three-nodes` is an alias of `three/examples/jsm/nodes`, therefore, if you have this issue you need to make your program recognize this alias. You can find way to do it in Vite from [this reply](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/24377#issuecomment-1199950847), or in rollup from the following config (with support of `@rollup/plugin-alias`)

```
{
    ...,
    plugins: [
        ...,
        alias({
            entries: [
                { find: 'three-nodes', replacement: 'three/examples/jsm/nodes' }
            ]
        })
    ]
}
```